# Dynamically selecting model object (t-shirt), then adding it to cart (by creating a line_item)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to build a shopping cart based on the Agile Web Development 4th edition.  The shopping cart is for selling t-shirts.  The t-shirts have various size options, color options, and gender options.  I want users to be able to select their options from lists, click "add to cart", and have the matching t-shirt added to to the cart (in the form of a line_item).

I think I am SO close to getting this done.  But not quite.  Here are the relevant code snippets:

The Form (/_store.html.erb):

```
<div id="storefunctions">
<%= form_tag '/line_items/create', :id => "tshirt" do %>
<div>
    size:&nbsp;<%= render 'size_select' %>&nbsp;
    color:&nbsp;<%= render 'color_select' %>&nbsp;
    gender:&nbsp;<%= render 'gender_select' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:message_content, @message.content) %></div
 <div> <%= submit_tag 'add to cart'  %></div>
<% end %>
```

Line_items Controller (/line_items/create.rb)

```
def create
@cart      = current_cart
tshirt     = Tshirt.where("size = ? AND gender = ? AND color = ?", params[:size], params[:gender], params[:color])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:tshirt_id => tshirt.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart, :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item, :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

When I click "add to cart" it says I have successfully added it to cart, but I can not access any information about the shirt.  It says it is a nil.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One note: `Model.where(...)` is going to be an array of results, not a single result object, so you can't call `.id` on it. You probably want `Tshirt.where("size = ? AND gender = ? AND color = ?", params[:size], params[:gender], params[:color]).first`

Comment: That solved the problem!  I KNEW it would be something simple like that!  Thanks!

Comment: Guess I'll resubmit it as an Answer then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.where(...)` is going to be an array of results, not a single result object, so you can't call `.id` on it. You probably want `Tshirt.where("size = ? AND gender = ? AND color = ?", params[:size], params[:gender], params[:color]).first`